# convert text to images with php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, gd

My codeigniter as bellow and result in text format.

```
<?php echo html_escape($trx->tr_id_payment) . PHP_EOL;?>
```

I need my buyer type and not copy paste result code above to their payment note.
How to convert this result to images format ? 
or any idea to force buyer type and not copy paste code result above ?

Comment: You can create image object, and print ```$trx->tr_id_payment``` on that. Then store that image on disk. Sure you can do this.